# Why jQueryUi selectable 'background-color' not work?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I tried to make work my library and I found that "background-color" CSS property not work when it used by jQueryUI. On the other hand if I simple use the "background" property with color value.
I make examples on jsfiddle:
- [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DqLHy/)
- [Not working example](http://jsfiddle.net/QFc4j/)
However is I simply make a class and apply to a div element in the html markup it works well.
Code:
HTML markup. Same in both cases:

```
<div id="selectable">
  <div class="ui-widget-content">1</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">2</div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">3</div>
</div>
```

Javascript. Also same in both case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectable").selectable();
});
```

CSS working scenario:

```
.ui-selected
  {
    background: rgb(255,0,0);
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
  }
```

CSS non-working scenario:

```
.ui-selected
  {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QFc4j/2/)

hi Peter, try putting the id in front of css, then it works.

```
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: rgb(255,0,0); color: white; }
```

Comment: Hi, Ali. Thanks for the answer but the problem is that if I use the background-color property then it's not working. If I use the background property it works fine without the id selector part.

Comment: Peter, why do you want to use background-color property when background just works fine?

Comment: If I only want to set the color of the background I usually use the exact property. For me it's much easyer to see/change. And I'm really curious what is the problem with the background-color propery in this case.